# Using PowerShell to send data from SQL Server to service via SOAP

Tags: web-services, powershell, soap

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and brand new (as in, today) to web services and SOAP. A vendor gave us documentation on their web service API that allows the creation of user accounts. I'm trying to use PowerShell to pull our users from SQL Server and send the data to their service. We will need to add users on an ongoing basis.

Below is a pared-down version of what I came up with and it actually seems to work; the vendor told me to include a `dry_run` parameter while testing and I'm getting a `dry_run_success` from the `response_type`.

My question is: Is this even close to being the appropriate way to do it with PowerShell?

```
# Open ADO.NET Connection to database
$dbConn = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$dbConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=mydbserver;User ID=someuserid;Password=mypassword;Initial Catalog=mydatabase";
$dbConn.Open();
$sql = "select * from mytable";
$dbSqlCmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $sql, $dbConn;
$dbRd = $dbSqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

# Create a Web Service Proxy
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri https://somedomain.com/service/wsdl
$namespace = $proxy.GetType().NameSpace
$param = New-Object($namespace + ".somemethod")

# Loop through records from SQL and invoke the web service
While ($dbRd.Read())
{
    $param.user_id = $dbRd.GetString(0)
    $param.password = $dbRd.GetString(1)
    $param.display_name = $dbRd.GetString(2)

    $request = $proxy.TheMethod($param)

    if ($request.response_type -eq 'error')
    {
        $request.error.extended_error_text
    }
}

# Clean up
$dbRd.Close();
$dbSqlCmd.Dispose();
$dbConn.Close();
```

Comment: Does the API allow you to send multiple requests in one call? If so, I'd recommend doing that over doing them individually.

Comment: I didn't think to ask them that but I will. Thank you!

Comment: I asked the vendor, and unfortunately they only allow one request per call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things you could improve:

1. Don't use `select *` in your SQL queries. Always specify the fields you need, in the order you need. As written, if someone were to restructure the table such that the user ID wasn't the first column, you'd have a mess on your hands because you're accessing the fields by their ordinal number
2. You're apparently storing those passwords in plaintext in your database. Anyone with access to your database knows the credentials for every one of your users. This is a very bad thing. Resolving this could be a *very* big discussion.
3. Your code keeps the database connection open until the script completes.  Given the scope here, it's *probably* not going to cause a major problem, but your database access strategy should be to get in, get your data, get out & disconnect as quickly as possible.

```bsh
$sql = "select user_id, password, display_name from mytable";
$QueryCmd = $dbConn();
$QueryCmd.CommandText = $sql;
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$QueryCmd.Connection = $dbConn;
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $QueryCmd;
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$dbConn.Close();
$dbConn.Dispose();

$MyResults = $DataSet.Tables[0];
$MyResults | foreach-object {
    $param.user_id = $_.user_id;
    $param.password = $_.password;
    $param.display_name = $_.display_name;

    $request = $proxy.TheMethod($param);

    if ($request.response_type -eq 'error')
    {
        $request.error.extended_error_text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback alroc.
1. I used `select *` for brevity. I'm only pulling the columns I need.
2. Yes, we're storing plaintext passwords. But for our purpose this truly is not a problem.
3. Thanks for this. I completley forgot that I could fill a dataset and use `ForEach-Object` (being fairly new and all :-).

Comment: Storing passwords in plaintext is **always** a problem.

Comment: A discussion for another time. :)