# API to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to write a script to load data from an API to a SQL Server. I want to automate this process so that it can be done weekly or monthly.

I have researched quite extensively and tried to find the best workaround. Here is what I have so far:

```
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json = #somehow I need a GET HTTP here, not sure how

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (id int 'strict $.id',
        PageViews nvarchar(50) '$.data.name.page_video_views')
```

Here is an example of the API data that I am pulling.

```
  {
      "data": [{
            "name": "page_video_views",
            "period": "day",
            "values": [{
              "value": 634,
              "end_time": "2018-11-23T08:00:00+0000"
            }, {
              "value": 465,
              "end_time": "2018-11-24T08:00:00+0000"
            }],
            "title": "Daily Total Video Views",
            "description": "Daily: Total number of times videos have been viewed for more than 3 seconds. (Total Count)"
}
```

What is the best way to read the data from the API and what is the best way to only select one of the two values that is returned from the API (e.g. 634 vs 465) above?

Comment: Which of the two do you want? Also that is not valid JSON. SELECT ISJSON(yourjsonval) returns 0

Comment: I would want the second value, 465. And sorry about the JSON, that is just an excerpt of the much larger JSON document

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you call a webservice from TSQL code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449/can-you-call-a-webservice-from-tsql-code)

Comment: although that question provides some solutions, not that `sp_OACreate` is very old and not recommended. If you must call a web service from T-SQL you're better of using CLR (which also has it's own issues). The best way to do it is have something external that calls the web service then pushes it in... like maybe powershell. Here's something that does that backwards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615803/using-powershell-to-send-data-from-sql-server-to-service-via-soap